# (Qt C++) QButtonGroup with Checkable PushButtons?

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

I'm working on a gui project in Qt Creator

How would I make a group of 40 push buttons set to checkable, but only one can be checked at a time? I looked into it a bit and QButtonGroup seemed interesting, but I just don't understand. :(

I have already laid out the 40 push buttons and set each one to checkable.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that you're adding 40 buttons programmatically, not manually in Qt Designer, so you should be able to create a list of all buttons: `QList<QPushButton*> my_buttons`. You need to create a button group and put all buttons into it. It's quite simple:

```
QButtonGroup* group = new QButtonGroup(this);
foreach(QPushButton* button, my_buttons) {
  group->addButton(button);
}
```

Comment: I have never added buttons programmatically, and Ii understand that it would be useful in the future, however, this group of 40 buttons are heavily dependent on their look. They are all aligned perfectly and sized exactly. (They go over a png)  Would it be possible to add the buttons I've already made to a group? perhaps one by one?

Comment: `QButtonGroup` doesn't affect form layout at all. From the docs: "It does not provide a visual representation of this container, but instead manages the states of each of the buttons in the group."

Comment: Yeah, but I meant, how could I add all the buttons I've already made into a QList? I don't understand a darn thing in that ui xml file. I'm not expecting you to write it for me (obviously) but I'm curious if there is a way to do it in the designer?

Comment: Each button is usually available as `ui->button_name` in your code where `button_name` is an unique button name assigned in Qt Designer. You can add all `ui->button_name` variables to a list manually. You can also use `findChildren<QPushButton*>()` to populate the list automatically. Or you can call `group->addButton(ui->button_name)` for each button separately if you don't want to make the list.

Comment: It works great! :) Thank you so much. Rai you've been helping me a lot lately XD